# invalid recursive type in a struct in go

Tags: go

I am new to the Go programming language and I have an assignment to create and interpreter but I am running into the following problem:

I want to define an Environment as:

```
type Environment struct{
    parent Environment
    symbol string
    value RCFAEValue
}

func (env Environment) lookup(lookupSymbol string) RCFAEValue{
    if lookupSymbol == env.symbol{
        return env.value
    } //if parent != nill {
        return env.parent.lookup(lookupSymbol)
}
```

But I get the error "invalid recursive type Environment".  Based on my research I changed the parent to type *Environment. But now when I need to create a new Environment with a var of type Environment it get the error "cannot use fun_Val.ds (type Environment) as type *Environment in field value".  I am creating the Environment as follows:

```
Environment{fun_Val.ds,fun_Val.param,exp.arg_exp.interp(env)}
```

I am trying to keep the amount of code in this post to a limit but if you need more, or have other questions please let me know.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You need to define `Environment` as:

```
type Environment struct {
    parent *Environment // note that this is now a pointer
    symbol string
    value  RCFAEValue
}
```

Otherwise the compiler has no way to figure out what the size of the Environment structure is. A pointer's size is known, but how big is something that contains itself? (And the inner struct contains itself as well, as does the inner inner struct, and so on.)

Creating the Environment will then look like:

```
Environment{&fun_Val.ds, fun_Val.param, exp.arg_exp.interp(env)}
```

Comment: "Otherwise the compiler has no way to figure out what the size of the Environment structure is."  That is false. The compiler knows exactly what the size of the Environment structure is: it is infinite. This knowledge by the compiler is the reason why the compiler rejected the code and said "invalid recursive type Environment".

Comment: @Atom, not so: the size of the Environment structure is _potentially_ infinite; the chain ends when there is an Environment with a null parent.  It's for that reason that some compilers, e.g. FPC, are able to handle analogous definitions.

Comment: @JasonFruit it is only nullable so long as you are using the pointer. If not, then it is *definitely* infinite as in the OP example because the inner struct's space have to be allocated as part of the outer struct's space.

Comment: Why does @JasonFruit's comment have more upvotes than @Atom's? It's wrong. Golang value types can't be null, nor can C++ or C. Wouldn't make sense, because the contents of a value-type field are stored directly in the context it's used. So yes, the Golang compiler knows it's infinite. Unless of course, the definition is just `type A struct {A}` - then it's 0, but still impossible to compile, since the depth is still infinite.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this should fix the problem:

```
Environment{&fun_Val.ds,fun_Val.param,exp.arg_exp.interp(env)}
```

(The `&` is the 'address of' operator in Go.)