# Entity association to itself with one-to-many relationships

Tags: go, model, associations, one-to-many, go-gorm

I use GORM to build model associations in Golang and I have a struct named **Category**. A category can have many children categories and it may have a parent category:

```
type Category struct {
 Name string `json:"name"`
 Parent Category `json:"parent_category"`
 ParentGroupID uint `json:"parent_group_id"`
 Children []Category `json:"children_categories"`
}
```

For this struct, I got an error for **Invalid recursive type Category**. I checked the GORM documentation but did not find anything helpful there. Any ideas how to model this kind of relation with GORM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare `Parent` as `*Category` (a pointer to `Category`) instead of `Category`.

```
type Category struct {
 Name string `json:"name"`
 Parent *Category `json:"parent_category"`
 ParentGroupID uint `json:"parent_group_id"`
 Children []Category `json:"children_categories"`
}
```

How does compiler know what the size of `Parent` is. A pointer's size is known, but how big is something that contains itself? (And the inner struct contains itself as well, as does the inner inner struct, and so on.)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261789/4794989